# NullInjectorError R3InjectorError(AppModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object]] with resolve

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting this weird error in Angular that I **think** has to do with the App Module as it's not giving me a specific location in **my** code. The error is this:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object]]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[[object Object] -> [object Object]]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for [object Object]!
at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:8771:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9200:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:9200:33)
    at getTokenOrFunctionIdentity (router.mjs:3086:29)
    at getResolver (router.mjs:4026:22)
    at router.mjs:4016:44
    at doInnerSub (mergeInternals.js:19:19)
    at outerNext (mergeInternals.js:14:57)
    at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
    at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1147:17)
    at zone.js:1260:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:25990:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25990:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26300:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
```

I did a bit of research about it and found out that this most likely has to do with services, but I am not sure.

All services in my app have are on the root component and have this decorator:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

Here's my App Modules:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    RecipesComponent,
    RecipeListComponent,
    RecipeDetailComponent,
    RecipeItemComponent,
    ShoppingListComponent,
    ShoppingEditComponent,
    DropdownDirective,
    RecipiesEditComponent,
    ToggleActiveClassDirective,
    DeleteDirective,
    AuthComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRouteModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

App Route Module:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'recipes',
        component: RecipesComponent,
        resolve: [{data: () => inject(HttpService).fetchRecipes()}],
        children: [
            {path: 'new', component: RecipiesEditComponent},
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: RecipeDetailComponent, 
                resolve: {detail: 
                    (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
                        let a = inject(RecipeService)
                        let b = inject(HttpService)
                        b.fetchRecipes()
                        return a.getRecipes()[route.params['id']]

                    }
                    
                    ,                     
            }},
            {path: ':id/edit', component: RecipiesEditComponent, resolve: {data: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => {
               let a = inject(RecipeService)
               a.getRecipes()[route.params['id']]
               let b = inject(HttpService)
               return b.fetchRecipes()
             } }}
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'shoppinglist',
        component: ShoppingListComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'auth',
        component: AuthComponent
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],

    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRouteModule {

}
```

If anyone has any suggestions on what I could do for this type of error, then that would be great.

P.S: I found a similar error but it said

> No Provider for AngularFireDatabase

Mine is `[Object object]`

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can try commenting code in your app module and routing module to see which part of code causes the error

Comment: what is `HttpService` and `RecipeService`

Comment: could you try to put those 2 services into the providers of AppModule?

Comment: @Andrei I actually commented the `resolve` key in appRoutes and then for some reason I wasn't getting the error, however, I need that `resolve` key for other things. Do you want me to post HttpService and RecipeService?

Comment: put them into the providers section of AppModule. I am 80% sure that it will resolve your problem. most likely both of those servcies depend on HttpClient and they can't find the HttpClient in the root injector, where they are provided

Comment: You have another problem in your app: for some reason (most likely you've done something that is not standart in the build configuration) the injection dependencies are stated as [Object object]. Usually those messages should be far more useful

Comment: @Andrei the problem is solved. `resolve` doesn't accept an array. Thanks btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resolve` accepts `ResolveData` which is defined as following :

```
type ResolveData = {
    [key: string | symbol]: ResolveFn<unknown> | DeprecatedGuard;
};
```

As you can see, it should not be an array, so

```
resolve: [{data: () => inject(HttpService).fetchRecipes()}],
```

should be :

```
resolve: {data: () => inject(HttpService).fetchRecipes()},
```

---

To why the compiler doesn't mind you passing an array we need to dig in into the type definition.

`type DeprecatedGuard` is defined as `ProviderToken<any>|any;` which is comparable to `any`.

So we have something that looks like :

```
type ResolveData = {
    [key: string | symbol]: any ;
};
```

This type is compatible to an array, that's why the compiler wasn't warning you of anything.

Comment: @Mattieu Riegler Thank you so much for the information, but just to be clear `DeprecatedGuard` refers to all the guards `canActivate`, `canDeactivate`, `resolve`, etc?

Comment: Yes, it referse to the "old" way of implenting them : class based.